# Possible limitation with updating a field in Advantage Database?

Tags: sql, database, advantage-database-server

I'm trying to update a field in a table and am unsure if I'm just completely wrong or if it's a possible limitation of using Advantage Database.

My Script:

*UPDATE myTable
SET myField = REPLACE(myField,substring(myField,myNumber,mynumber),'<>')
Where myField = '<>';*

The error I receive is "Expected lexical element not found:  -- Missing table name. You are missing the table name after the keyword UPDATE. -- Location of error in the
SQL statement is: 8"

Comment: Very likely to be an error on your part. Try writing a simple script to illustrate the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224106/adding-value-plus-1-each-time-as-an-update for an example script that creates a temporary table and updates it.

Answer (score 1):

Please show the actual statement that produced the "missing table name" error. The statement you gave is syntactically correct.

```
DECLARE myNumber INTEGER;
myNumber = 1;

//TRY DROP TABLE myTable; CATCH ALL END TRY;

CREATE TABLE myTable
(
  id AUTOINC,
  myField VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO myTable (myField) VALUES ('<>');

UPDATE myTable
  SET myField = REPLACE(myField, SUBSTRING(myField, myNumber, myNumber), '<>')
  WHERE myField = '<>';
```

Result:

> SUCCESS: 2 Rows Affected